# Validate variable in PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to write a PHPUnit test, so I created a test file in `./test` and this is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;


use Validator;
use Tests\TestCase;

class NationalCodeTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testMyCode()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(Validator::numeric('0123456'));
    }
}
```

but when I run phpunit I get this error:

```
Error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Factory::number()
```

I'm newbie in Laravel PHPUnit, so I don't know is this the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and for others who have this problem, I write the solution here.

I used `numeric` static method in mistake for `Validator` (it's my stupid mistake  :)) ), I should use `make` static method and pass the values and rules,

So I rewrite my code:

```
 public function testMyCode()
    {
        $values = [
            'num' => '0123456'
        ];

        $test = Validator::make($values,[
            'num' => 'numeric'
        ]);

        $this->assertFalse($test->fails());
    }
```

I hope useful for others :)